# Calculate $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^{2}}{\rm d}t$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives

> Calculate $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^{2}}{\rm d}t$

An answer given online that uses fundamental theorem of calculus is that lets $\displaystyle F\left ( x \right )= \int_{0}^{x}e^{t^{2}}{\rm d}t,$ then
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^{2}}{\rm d}t= {F}'\left ( 0 \right )= e^{0}= 1$$
But this doesn't quite make sense to me. Where do the $1/x$ and the limit go ?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: It's probably L'Hospital, or just the definition of a derivative of a function at $0$

Comment: It makes no sense to us either

Comment: That online answer is the most straightforward approach to evaluate this limit. You need to revisit fundamental theorem of calculus in your textbook.

Answer (score 3):

$F(0) = 0$, so the integral can be written as
$$\int_0^x e^{t^2}\ dt = F(x) - F(0).$$
Therefore,
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x e^{t^2}\ dt = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{F(x) - F(0)}{x} = F'(0)$$
where the last equality follows directly from the definition of the derivative.

The integrand $e^{t^2}$ is continuous, so by the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have
$$F'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x e^{t^2}\ dt = e^{x^2}$$
and from this it follows that
$$F'(0) = e^{0^2} = e^0 = 1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\lim_{x→0}\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x e^{t^2}\ dt=\lim_{x→0}\frac{\int_0^x e^{t^2}\ dt}{x} \left(\frac 00 \text{form}\right)$$
So we have to use the L'Hospital rule.
$$L=\lim_{x→0}\dfrac{\frac d{dx}\int_0^x e^{t^2}\ dt}{\frac d{dx}x}=\lim_{x→0}\frac{ e^{x^2}}{1} =e^0=1.$$

.....................................................

**First fundamental theorem of calculus:** Let $f$ be a continuous real-valued function defined on a closed interval $[a, b]$. Let $F$ be the function defined, for all $x$ in $[a, b]$, by

$$F(x)=\int _{a}^{x}\!f(t)\,dt~.$$
Then $F$ is uniformly continuous on $[a, b]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(a, b)$, and

$$F'(x)=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\int _{a}^{x}\!f(t)\,dt\right)=f(x)\,$$
for all $x$ in $(a, b)~.$

Answer (score 0):

We may think as $x> 0.$ According to mean-value theorem$,\quad\exists c\in\left ( 0, x \right )$ so that
$$\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}\exp t^{2}{\rm d}t= \exp c^{2}\rightarrow\exp 0= 1\,{\rm as}\,x\rightarrow 0^{+}$$